# How to poll a directory and if the any xlsx file copied in the directory call an REST api to load the feed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a use case, i want to poll a directory, if the any .*xlsx file get pasted in that directory, i want to call a post rest API that will load the data.
I'm not able to find the my way, please suggest some way to do this.

Comment: Use a file poller in Spring Integration then send the file to an endpoint.

Comment: In my case, we just need to trigger a rest call if anyone put xlsx file in that directory. Pls provide some example if possible.(we already have a api with it's own functionality, i want to call this api if anyone put the xlsx fine in that directory)

Comment: Check the Spring Integration samples and documentation that have a ready to use sample (you can just ignore the payload and just call the API you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for fully working sample and I doubt that is going to be one since your business task might not be the same what other people are doing.

Although we won't mind if you contribute back such a sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.

1. So, to build a logic we need to provide an `IntegrationFlow`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl.
2. To read files from a dir we need to use a `Files.inboundAdapter()` with respective polling policy.
3. You may do some transformation (`.transform()`) about polled file content or so.
4. Call the REST service via `Http.outboundGateway()`
5. Do the post-process.

Something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("myDir"))
                                .patternFilter("*.xlsx"),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .transform(...)
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("")
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                .transform(...)
                .get();
    }
```

(Haven't checked as working since I don't know what is your XSLT content and how you call the REST service.)

This sample does something with files reading to gather some ideas: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/applications/file-split-ftp

Comment: Thank @Artem, this what I was looking for. Everything working as expected but after the api call I'm getting a error "no output-channel or reply-channel header available". Also can we delete the file once the api call done??

Comment: Right . The gateway expects to send its reply to some other channel. That’s why I showed you that `transform()` in the end of flow. You can have that channel as a publish-subscribe, so you will be able to call `File.delete()` in parallel with reply processing. An original file is stored in the `FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

We have a system that does (almost) the same (just xml instead of xlsx) and we use Apache Camel https://camel.apache.org/

Integration is good with Spring Boot. You just need to define your route `from("file:///<path").to("http:<host>:port/<path>)` and it will do probably what you need.

Might need to tweek the line of code to get filtering and maybe add some transformation but it is a nice peace of software.

Comment: Can't we do it using spring-integration ?? I'm looking the ways using spring-integration